# SSAS Controls with decomposition tree

Tags: .net, ssas, data-warehouse, olap, performancepoint

I am currently working on an BI solution and I need to make some design decisions. We have already made the ELT process and have designed the cube in SSAS so now we need to present the data to the end user.

The senario is as follows. We have the measures, KPIs and dimensions and we know what data we need to present to the End-User.

An easy solution would be to use a Sharepoint server via PerfomancePoint-Dashboard designer which provides a decomposition tree amongst the OLAP controls it offers. The problem here is that we only need to show the data generated from the cube. There is no need for any of the collaboration and/or content management features of sharepoint.

Another would be to make a new web application (WebForms for example) using one of the 3rd party olap tools for .Net! This I suppose would be simpler from a development point of view but no decomposition tree is a deal breaker for us.

The most important question here is, if there are any olap Controls out there (3rd party or not) that include a decomposition tree.

Is there any way (in the form of a library) to strip the OLAP controls from sharepoint and use them in a web forms project?

Is it possible - and if it is, is it a proper practice - to strip the sharepoint site of any additional controls and leave only the dashboard surrounded by any theme we choose?

How would you advise me to present the SSAS data to a client who is a simple user with little to none IT knowledge who just wants to view statistics and charts without needing/wanting to understand an entire new and complex environment?

Answer (score 1):

which version of SQL Server are you using? If you are already on 2012 you should give Power View a try, it is very intuitive and completely integrated with Sharepoint (but it needs to be Sharepoint 2010)

Comment: Unfortunately we are still on sql-server 2008. Power view would be a nice way to present my data but I would be interested in something along the line of RadarSoft tools (the charts not the Grid), with a decomposition tree feature.